# Getting started with Google VR in Unity on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel, daydream

I am following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/get-started
I have a Google Pixel. I am using JDK 9.0.1. I am trying to build this on a MAC OS Sierra.
I get the following error when I 'Build and Run' the GVRDemo: "Resource Compilation Failed! Failed to recompile android resource files."
I tried setting the JAVA_HOME path to make sure it's pointing to the current JDK, and even changed it in Unity preferences. I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to check that in build setting you already switch the platform to IOS.
after that do check it that Virtual reality support is checked in other setting and cardboard is selected too.